# Spark java fails on filter

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a java code calling using spark (2.1.0).
The entire calculation (read from json (as dataset) -> filter some data -> calculate new column using UDF) is done correctly (using `ds.show()`).

In the last step I want to filter only records where the new column is greater than one of the other columns -
`ds.where(col("new_col").gt(col("mycol")));`

> This fails with the following error -  Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression:
>   some_col_name#138L

I find it weird since `some_col_name` is not part of the filtering (but part of how `new_col`is calculated and when I write it to file (before filtering) it is written correctly.

Any ideas? Known issue?

Rough example of my code

```
private static java.util.List<Row> runReport(SparkSession spark, String[] dateColumns, String input_files)
            throws AnalysisException {
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json(input_files);
        Dataset<Row> ds = df.groupBy("user").pivot("data").sum("my_col");
        ds = ds.na().fill(0f);
        ds = ds.withColumn("some_col", lit(100L));
        final Dataset<Row> ds2 = ds;
        List<Column> columns = Arrays.stream(dateColumns).map(x -> ds2.col(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Seq<Column> seqColumns = scala.collection.JavaConverters.
                asScalaIteratorConverter(columns.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
        ds = ds.withColumn("arrayData", array(seqColumns));
        UDF1 avgArray = new UDF1<Seq<Long>, Long>() {
            public Long call(final Seq<Long> arr) throws Exception {
                // calculate average
            }
        };

        UDF3 newGoal = new UDF3<Seq<Long>, Long, Long, Long>() {
            public Long call(Seq<Long> steps, Long goal, Long average) throws Exception {
                boolean all_above_goal = true;
                // Goal does not change if the average is below the goal
                // some logic - returns long
                return 100L;
            }
        };

        spark.udf().register("avgArray", avgArray, DataTypes.LongType);
        spark.udf().register("newGoal", newGoal, DataTypes.LongType);
        ds = ds.selectExpr("userId", "goal", "newGoal(arrayData, some_col, avgArray(arrayData)) as new_some_col");
        ds = ds.where(col("col1").gt(col("col2")));
        return  ds.collectAsList();
    }
```

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: edited and added

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a column named `"new_goal"` in your dataframe `ds`.

Comment: I do have, just failed when removing identifying signals. All columns exists and when I do ds.show() before filtering everything is calculated correctly. The part which fails is the filtering.

Comment: @TomRon I don't see a `filter` operation. Or do you mean the `selectExpr` line with the UDF?

Comment: I refered to the -  `ds = ds.where(col("col1").gt(col("col2")));`